# How do you pronounce "Duclos est un homme"?

Tags: prononciation, liaisons

Typically when one word ends in a consonant it is dropped and becomes the first sounds of the next word if it begins with a vowel (*liaison*).

> Duclos est un homme.

Why is the *s* in *Duclos* not sounded when followed by *est* then?

What is the exact rule that governs that?

Comment: OP is a new contributor, their first question was good, its formatting has been improved, imho the question should have been upvoted. The +2 answer exists because the question was asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because this is [forbidden](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3552) following a *singular noun* and a first name is subsumed under that. It's not obvious it is but the following example from *Le bon usage* 14 (Grevisse & Goosse) § 44 c in the "liaisons inusitées (outre les cas où il y a pause ou disjonction)" [*irregular* (except for when there is a pause of disjunction)] section, makes it clear: "après la consonne finale d'un nom au singulier [following the final consonant of a singular noun] [...] ***Vincent*** **|** ***ira*** [will go/will be going]".

---

En résumé la liaison est interdite/inusitée après la consonne finale d'un nom au singulier et un prénom est assimilé à un nom au singulier tel que l'illustre l'exemple au LBU14 § 44 c) « ***Vincent*** **|** ***ira*** ».